# Multiple FinalPriceBox Block customizations

Tags: magento2, layout, dependency-injection

I have 2 customizations of the `FinalPriceBox` block, one I would like to be the default for the site, the other only on the product view page. I've added a layout update *view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml* to my custom module; in there I specify a custom block `FinalPriceBoxGeneral` and template `final_price_general.phtml`

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool" name="render.product.prices">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Moxune\Amazing\Block\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBoxGeneral</item>
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Moxune_Amazing::product/price/final_price_general.phtml</item>
```

This works to change the block & template **everywhere** on the site.

I've now tried to get change the block and template on just the product view page by adding to *view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml* in my plugin

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="render.product.prices">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Moxune\Amazing\Block\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBoxDetail</item>
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Moxune_Amazing::product/price/final_price_detail.phtml</item>
```

However this seems to have no effect on the product view page.

Answer (score 2):

I got this working by creating a custom price type which you can read about in this [magento dev doc](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/architecture/behavior/pricing.html#m2devgde-pricelib-def). Specifically, they say

> To add a custom price type, create a corresponding class extending
>   AbstractPrice.

So I created a simple class `Moxune\Amazing\Pricing\DetailPrice`

```
namespace Moxune\Amazing\Pricing;

class DetailPrice extends \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice
{
    const PRICE_CODE = 'detail_price';
}
```

add the new price type, `detail_price` in *di.xml*

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\Pool" type="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\Pool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="prices" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="detail_price" xsi:type="string">Moxune\Amazing\Pricing\DetailPrice</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Now, the layout update for the product detail page becomes, changing `price_type_code` to `detail_price` (the new price type)

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="product.info.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-main" before="-">
                <container name="product.info.price" label="Product info auxiliary container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-price" after="product.info.review">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.review" template="product/view/review.phtml" after="product.info.stock.sku" />
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.final" after="product.info.sku">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                            <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">detail_price</argument>
                            <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
```